# PHP - Web crawler not printing title or description

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am making a very basic web crawler in PHP as a project while I wait for CS50, here's what I have so far.

```
<?php

$start = "http://localhost/~jordanbaron/Web%20Crawler/input.html";

$already_crawled = array();

function get_details($url)
{
  global $already_crawled;

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  @$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('method'=> "GET", 'headers'=>"User-Agent: jordanBot\n")))));

  $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
  $title = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $description = "";
  $keywords = "";
  $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName("meta");

  for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
  {
    $meta = $metas->item($i);

    if ($meta->getAttribute("name") == strtolower("description"))
      $description = $meta->getAttribute("content");
    if ($meta->getAttribute("name") == strtolower("keywords"))
      $keywords = $meta->getAttribute("content");
  }
  return '{ "Title": "'.$title.'", "Description": "'.str_replace("\n", "", $description).'", "Keywords": "'.$keywords.'"}';
}

function follow_links($url)
{

  global $already_crawled;

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  @$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('method'=> "GET", 'headers'=>"User-Agent: jordanBot\n")))));

  $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");

  foreach ($linklist as $link)
  {
    $l = $link->getAttribute("href")."\n";


    if (substr($l, 0, 1) == "/" && substr($l, 0, 2) != "//")
    {
      $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].$l;
    }
    else if (substr($l, 0, 2) == "//")
    {
      $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"].":".$l;

    }
    else if (substr($l, 0, 2) == "./")
    {
      $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].dirname(parse_url($url)["path"]).substr($l, 1);
    }
    else if (substr($l, 0, 1) == "#")
    {
      $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].parse_url($url)["path"].$l;
    }
    else if (substr($l, 0, 3) == "../")
    {
      $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"]."/".$l;
    }
    else if (substr($l, 0, 5) != "https" && substr($l, 0, 4) != "http")
    {
      $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"]."/".$l;
    }
    else if (substr($s, 0, 11) == "javascript:")
    {
      continue;
    }

    if (!in_array($l, $already_crawled))
    {
      $already_crawled[] = $l;
      echo get_details($l)."\n";
      //echo $l."\n";
    }


  }
}

follow_links($start);

print_r($already_crawled);
```

A problem that I am having is that for the google.com `<a>` tag I get this as a result `{ "Title": "", "Description": "", "Keywords": ""}` instead of something like this `{ "Title": "Google", "Description": "", "Keywords": ""}` If it helps I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bYlBiSExI0) tutorial by howCode

Comment: Don't make JSON by concatenating strings, put the data in an array and call `json_encode()`. Why are you returning JSON from the function anyway, just return an array and call `json_encode()` later, when you need to serialize all the results.

Comment: First of all never use `@` while calling functions. Because of that you know nothing about what is going on in your code. Remove it and read errors that will show up.

Comment: `if ($meta->getAttribute("name") == strtolower("description"))` should be `if (strtolower($meta->getAttribute("name")) =="description")`. You don't need to convert a literal string that's already lowercase to lowercase.

Comment: You're calling `get_details()` with an argument, but it doesn't take any arguments, the URL is hard-coded in the function.

Comment: None of that worked.